MAMP 7 upgrade 'Apache couldn't be started' but runs okay from terminal; symlinks for PHP broken
I've upgraded the devops tool MAMP, with the Apache or Nginx web servers, MySQL database server and PHP, from MAMP 6 to MAMP 7 on macOS and when I start MAMP, I get a dialogue that says:

'Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration.'

There is nothing in /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log for the time when I try to start it.
If I do /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start in terminal, then it starts, but the log then says:
/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php.fcgi: line 4: exec: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.3.1/bin/php-cgi: cannot execute: No such file or directory
/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php.fcgi: line 4: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.3.1/bin/php-cgi: No such file or directory

This is very strange, as MAMP is set to run 8.3.8.
Furthermore there is a symlink /Applications/MAMP/conf/php8.3.1 which is broken, as its target /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.3.1/conf doesn't exist -- there is no php8.3.1 folder.
Also, having started Apache from the terminal, URL rewrites aren't working.
P.S. There are other questions about the same error message but as far as I can tell, they are all about much older versions of MAMP.

Why has this been closed? It is about MAMP which MOST DEFINITELY IS 'software tools primarily used by programmers.'

This is very relevant to software development.  :)  My solution was to edit the file fcgi-bin/php.fcgi and change 8.3.1 to 8.3.9 - problem solved.

joachim, I regret I tried to improve your post with the hope to get it opened. Thank you for putting light on this problem. I had to go back to MAMP because a tool I use did malfunction in Docker. @Justin Dunn's answer got me on track for the solution to MAMP not starting up properly.

FFS. MAMP is a developer tool! Could the person who closed this and refuses to reopen this comment with their reasons?

Install the 14-day trial of MAMP Pro and start it up. Then, close MAMP Pro and open MAMP.

This also worked for me. It updated the SSL certs, allowing the free version to fully start.

Wow, that just worked for me too! I clicked the 'Try MAMP pro now' button in the top right of the MAMP window. The process took AGES and seemed to freeze on the 'Copying files from SITES FOLDER to SITES FOLDER' step, so I restarted my machine to kill it. And now I just ran MAMP and my sites work again!

Ok, it's not working entirely -- it's not using the version of PHP that's selected in the UI. The file fcgi-bin/php.fcgi has the wrong PHP version in it.

If you have run the trial before and it has expired, you don't need to do more than starting MAMP PRO once, after which Apache will start fine in MAMP.

Re-enabling mod_rewrite in MAMP 7.
While there is already good answer about launching MAMP Pro prior to launching plain old MAMP, I feel this issue reported by the original poster was not addressed:

“Also, having started Apache from the terminal, URL rewrites aren't working.”

Looking in the Apache log in MAMP shows tons of lines like this when attempting to access projects that have .htaccess directives with RewriteEngine on and such:
.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

The way to fix this is to open up httpd.conf file in the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache directory and go to line 179; shown here:
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Why that core mod_rewrite functionality disabled by default? No idea. But just uncomment that line as shown below:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Stop and start the servers again in MAMP and you should be good to go! Your projects will start working again.
MySQL binary location related changes in MAMP 7.
In addition to that mod_rewrite issue, you might run into issues when attempting to run mysql and mysqldump from the command line.
The reason is MAMP 7 is bundled with MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0. So each of those binaries (mysql and mysqldump) are stored in their relative versions directory:
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql57/bin
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql80/bin

A quick and simple way to clear up this issue is to go into the main bin/ directory from the Terminal like so:
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin

And create symbolic links like so; I am choosing MySQL 8.0 in this example since MySQL 8.0 is the default database of MAMP nowadays:
ln -s mysql80/bin/mysqldump mysqldump
ln -s mysql80/bin/mysql mysql

MySQL database files location related changes in MAMP 7.
And finally, the actual MySQL database files are similarly stored in their relative versions directory:
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql80

If you are upgrading from from MAMP 6.9, your database files might all be in the /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57 directory.
To get them loaded into MySQL 8.0 (the default database of MAMP) just stop all MAMP servers and delete the default MySQL 8.0 files:
rm -rf /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql80

Then move the mysql57/ directory to mysql80/ like so:
mv /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57 /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql80

Stop and start the servers again in MAMP and you should be good to go! Your databases should all now be present in MySQL 8.0 which can be checked/confirmed by going to the phpMyAdmin URL: http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin5/
